# Как определить, а потом отконвертировать любое значение в цифровое int?

Tags: c#, консоль

Извините, но я только начал изучать C#, появилась куча вопросов.

1. Первый и самый непонятный для меня вопрос: почему все так строго?
   К примеру, я не могу в методе вернуть значение, кроме того, что указано в заголовке метода, или переменная, если она int, я не могу запихать туда, к примеру, стринговые значения или дату.
   Зачем такая строгость?
2. Во всех языках такая строгость? (Языки типа C++ и т.д.)
3. Ну и третий вопрос собственно по теме.
     Консольное приложение (самое простое) и запросе с клавиатуры:

   Console.WriteLine("Введите любой символ");
   int result = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Если ввести символ, не цифру или просто нажать на enter  - выдает ошибку. Как ее исправить?
А точней, как понять, что введеный символ цифра, буква или просто enter.

Повторюсь: только начал изучать. Ни функций, ни пространств имен для работы не знаю.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: > немогу

Частица "не" пишется с глаголами раздельно. Кроме глаголов, где она уже давно не частица, а часть глагола (ненавидеть, например).

> запихать туда к примеру стринговые значения или дату.

Зачем запихивать туда какой-то произвольный вывод? C# позволяет работать довольно атомарно, выполняя операции с абсолютно предсказуемым типом значения. Если вкратце, то это требуется для самого языка, передавать произвольные значения выходит несколько дороже.

> Во всех языках такая строгость?

В строго типизированных (ява, сишка и плюсы, шарп) - да.

Comment: > Если ввести символ, не цифру или просто нажать на enter выдает ошибку. Как ее исправить?

Интернет подсказывает мне, что

    int number;
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), number)) {
        // содержимое строки - не целое число
    }

Comment: Ok попробую!

Comment: >Частица "не" пишется с глаголами раздельно

@Etki не будьте занудой) Человек, пришедший сюда, меньше всего хочет услышать лекцию о правописании, и, скорее всего, забудет о ней через минуту после прочтения, поскольку искал тут не это

Comment: @max3000:

> переменная, если она int, я не могу запихать туда, к примеру, стринговые значения или дату.

Если вы хотите «запихать» туда дату, что ж вы объявляете переменную типа `int`? Объявите её типа `object` и кладите туда всё, что вам вздумается.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Почему все так строго? К примеру, я не могу в методе вернуть значение кроме того, что указано в заголовке метода или вот переменная, если она int я не могу запихать туда к примеру строковые значения или дату.

Потому что это уберегает вас от кучи ошибок и облегчает понимание кода.
Скажем, у вас есть некий метод:

```
class Person 
{
    // ...

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _name
    }
}
```

скажем, используете его вы вот так:

```
int age = person,GetName();
```

однако язык строго типизирован, а потому в коде строчкой выше вы получите ошибку компиляции - ваша программа просто не запустится, так как `GetName` возвращает `string?` тогда как его результат вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной типа int. Вы, вероятно, скажете "блин, так это же плохо - получать ошибки". И будете неправы - ошибки компиляции - это очень хорошо. Вы ее можете сразу увидеть и исправить. А теперь представьте, что вы действительно можете присваивать переменной типа `int` любое значение. То есть вышеприведенный код компилируется. Чем вам это грозит? Довольно неприятными последствиями, которые вы не сможете определить на этапе компиляции. Уже во время запуска программы ваша переменная `age` (которая, судя по названию, хранит чей-то возраст) будет иметь значение "Вася". Увидеть вы это сможете уже гораздо позже, и выявление и исправление такой ошибки будет гораздо дороже.
Пример довольно упрощенный, и подобных ошибок может быть очень много. Хотя с ними можно бороться, все же это лишняя трата времени и средств.

Второе преимущество - это более удобный анализ языка. Код с со строгой типизацией более удобен для анализирования (как автоматического так и ручного) и вам не нужно ковыряться в недрах кода или танцевать с отладчиком, увидев такую конструкцию:

```
var foo = GetFoo();
```

чтобы понять что же такое возвращает метод. Достаточно просто перейти к объявлению того, что скрывается под `**var**`.

> Во всех языках такая строгость? (языки типа C++ и т.д.)

не во всех. Хотя и во многих (в том числе и в С++). Есть немало языков с динамической типизацией, там возможны самые различные фокусы с типами. Например JavaScript или PHP.

По поводу последнего вопроса. Здесь, как верно подсказал вам @Etki, вы можете воспользоваться методом `TryParse`. Только в приведенном примере была небольшая ошибка, вот исправленный вариант:

```
int number;
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)) {
    // содержимое строки - не целое число
}
```

Еще можно просто воспользоваться исключениями. Что-то наподобие:

```
string data = "qwerty";
try 
{
    Console.WriteLine("number is {0}", Convert.ToInt32(data));
}
catch(FormatException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Данная строка не может быть преобразована в число");
}
catch(OverflowException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Данная строка содержит число размером более 4 байт");
}
```

Comment: спасибо за разяснение.

Comment: А зачем нужен overFlow? из-за битности ?

Comment: >А зачем нужен overFlow? из-за битности ?

о чем вы?